# Is it possible to determine if a website has been encoded?

Tags: php, base64, encode, google-ads-api

So here's the problem leading to that question: I've got a tracking script that is causing my Google Ads text ads to be disapproved for having "Malicious or unwanted software." Neither is on the script.

The PHP script is encoded using eval(gzinflate(substr(base64_decode. Since hacked websites are often encoded (again, the one in question is not hacked), I'm wondering if Google is able to recognized that the site is encoded and that's triggering the red flag.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Well, try skipping that encoding step and see. That said, Google doesn't see your PHP code at all, just the resulting output. Put your site URL in https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search and see if it's flagged.

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, Google cannot see your PHP code. The more likely explanation is that you have some suspicious-looking Javascript in your site somewhere.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for that link! It said the site was safe, so at least I can mention that while I'm arguing with them. I didn't think Google could tell it was encoded, but... you know... it's Google. I figured if anyone could, they could. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: It's not unheard of for false positives to be caused by JS minifiers etc. Or, perhaps it's your tracking alone they object to.